# Having trouble setting up the limits of integration.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $E$ be the solid below the plane $z=8$ and above the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Find the mass of $E$ if the density $\rho(x,y,z)=z$.

I'm supposed to use triple integrals with cylindrical coordinates.

I know theta will be integrated from $0$ to $2\pi$.

I think the radius is $0$ to $8$ from setting $8=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and getting $64=x^2+y^2$

Not quite sure about $z$. My guess is that its from $0$ to $8$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $M$ your mass.  Then you want to compute $M = \int\int\int \rho(z) rdrd\theta dz$.  The thing you want to observe is that when you integrate with respect to $z$ you're not starting at $z=0$ for each value of $x$ and $y$, you're actually starting at the height $8-r$.  Therefore your integral should be

$$
M \;\; =\;\; \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^8 \int_{8-r}^8 r\rho(z) dzdrd\theta.
$$